# How to charge a capacitor with an AC supply?

Tags: ac, charging

I have tried charging a capacitor and it can easily be done with a DC power source. But the Voltage needs to be >200 and so i only have an AC availabe at hand. The capacitor is >200 V and so is the AC source. And someone give me a detailed answer with a circuit abput how i can charge my cap ?

Comment: Convert the AC to DC with a diode (or diode bridge). You will never charge a capacitor with AC.

Comment: Use a diode rectifier but beware of the maximum voltages that might be bigger than your capacitors ratings.

Comment: If you have to ask this then I have my doubts about you having enough knowledge and understanding to **safely** charge and use anything with more than 200 V DC on it. **200 V DC on a capacitor can be enough to kill you !**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner does not have enough knowledge to make use of an answer safely.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve with the capacitor. Why > 200V, How much capacitance? What is the AC voltage in RMS volts? What is the capacitor voltage rating? | Death is easy with what you describe.

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid that the AC source you are refering to is your AC mains connection.

Altough charging a capacitor with a diode or diode bridge is not to difficult it  can be **VERY** dangerous if you do not understand very well what you are doing.

Even if you are able to do all of that in a possible safe manner then you are still facing a dangerous situation if are using your mains supply as the AC source.

On top of the warning from FakeMoustache an additional one.

**In order not to kill yourself please stay away from working with high voltages**